# Get Distinct value using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using one table that has user name and work duration of that user. The collection has multiple duration hours for the same user. I want to display the distinct user name and sum of duration hours for that user name.

```
db.collection.aggregate([       
    { "$match": { FacilityID: '59a53f0c6077b2a029c52b7f', ProjectID: '59c1171f734bcb3038e2bb67'} },
    { "$group": { _id: { TeamMemberUserID: "$TeamMemberUserID",Duration: "$Duration"}} },
    { "$project": { TeamMemberUserID: "$_id.TeamMemberUserID", _id: 0, Duration: "$_id.Duration", _id: 0} }
])
```

it is displaying username 3 times and showing

```
siva 40
siva 40
siva 40
```

for that user has different Duration for different kind of work like: 20 hours for designing, 10 hours for coding, 10 for Testing.

but I want display the user with the sum of duration hours of all his work.

```
User Name:    Phase       duration
Siva          Testing      10
siva          Coding       10
siva          Designing    20
```

Expecting output:

```
Siva 40
```

The above query executing username while grouping with duration hours. The duration hours is vary due to that it is displaying username according to the duration.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include some sample documents from the collection and your expected output documents?

Comment: Please add the documents that match your query. For ex: `FacilityID` is not there in document.

Comment: based on the FacilityID  I am selecting the user. That is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator to `$Duration` instead of including it in the `_id` of the `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([       
    { "$match": { FacilityID: '59a53f0c6077b2a029c52b7f', ProjectID: '59c1171f734bcb3038e2bb67'} },
    { "$group": { _id: "$TeamMemberUserID", Duration: {$sum: "$Duration"} } },
    { "$project": { TeamMemberUserID: "$_id", _id: 0, Duration: 1 } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnnyHK

Comment: yes sure. I have marked as answer by clicking the tick symbol